# Angular2: RadioButton change event is not binding

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, radio-button, dom-events

Here, I want to simply bind RadioButton with change event. Not using any library.

Following works fine.

```
<input type="radio" name="test" value="A" (change)="onPropertyChange('test')">
<input type="radio" name="test" value="B" (change)="onPropertyChange('test')">
```

But this one is not :

```
<div class="btn-group col-lg-2" data-toggle="buttons" >
<label *ngFor=" let app of applications; let i = index; " 
       class="btn btn-default " [ngClass]="{'active':( ticket.app == app)}">      
      <input type="radio" id="app{{i}}"  name="app" value="{{i}}"                   
           checked="{{ ( ticket.app == app ) ? 'checked' : ''}}" (change)=" 
           onPropertyChange('app')"  > 
     {{app}}
</label>
</div>
```

While binding change event to label, it is giving me old value.

Can anyone suggest right approach?

Comment: You should not rely on Bootstrap javascript when you deal with Angular. Your problem is `data-toggle="buttons"`

Comment: add onPropertyChange Function ts code

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/YMQcwsBW0ems1dyEGJ8G?p=preview

Comment: The `change` event is fired only when the radio is checked. In your case you hardcoded the value you pass to your function `onPropertyChange('app')`. You might want to change that to `onPropertyChange(i)`

Comment: Thanks @yurzui for suggesting right approach. Very helpful.

Comment: @AngJobs : yes, it is also working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ng2-bootstrap,

```
<div class="btn-group col-lg-2">
    <label *ngFor="let app of applications" class="btn btn-default" [(ngModel)]="ticket.app" btnRadio="{{app}}">{{app}}</label>
</div>
```

In .ts file,

- Added `import { ButtonRadioDirective } from 'ng2-bootstrap/components/buttons';`
- In `@Component` annotation, passed it as `directives: [ButtonRadioDirective]`.

It works fine. Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

With Angular 2 RC2 it’s no longer needed to create the RadioButtonState:

> Radio Buttons can now share FormControl instance

```
<form #f="ngForm">
   <input type="radio" name="food" [(ngModel)]="food" value="chicken">
   <input type="radio" name="food" [(ngModel)]="food" value="fish">
</form>
```

And:

```
class MyComp {
   food = 'fish';
}
```

Source: [5thingsangular - Issue #8](http://5thingsangular.github.io/2016/06/20/issue-8.html)

Answer (score 1):

Two way binding without a library:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default" [class.active]="yourVariable==item" (click)="yourVariable=item" *ngFor="let item of items">
        <input type="radio" style="display: none;" name="radios" [(ngModel)]="yourVariable" [value]="item" [checked]="yourVariable==item" />
        {{yourLabelText}}
    </label>
</div>
```